# Passing through USB3 device in qemu 4.2.0 from CLI

Tags: linux, usb, qemu

I try to pass through a USB3 device into qemu guests (Debian or Win10). The concerning parts of the start script are:

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci \
    -device usb-host,hostbus=2,hostport=3,id=usb23 \
# way more parameters
```

I already tried `nec-usb-xhci` and `qemu-xhci` as host controller, and I can see either popping up in both guest OSes (either in the Device Manager GUI, or in `lspci` on Debian). Whatsoever, the USB device never pops up. On Win10, I have got no other clue than observing the Device Manager, on Debian I looked in `lsusb` for the device without avail.

As main info source, I used [this qemu GitHub](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/usb2.txt), but the info on USB 3 is as brief as it only could be.

Can anyone help to narrow down or solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy: either `qemu` needs elevated rights, or you need to `chown` the usb devices. I used option no 1.

See:
https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#host_005fusb_005fdevices

Comment: Pro tip: If you need to figure out your hostbus and hostport, you can either use ```lsusb -t``` and search, or you can use ```info usbhost``` in the qemu console.