# QEMU on Windows Host - Passthrough USB Device

Tags: windows, usb, qemu

I'm new about QEMU, I normally use VirtualBox but I need a no Admin system.
I have Windows 11 Pro with QEMU and I virtualize a Windows 10.
Now I want to connect a USB device (USB3 - pendrive) to have a connection between Host and Guest.
I use the command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 32768 Win10.img -smp 16 -smp cores=4 -M accel=whpx -device qemu-xhci -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x0781,productid=0x5591
```

The vendorId and productID are taken using USBDeview.

When I run the machine, I don't find the device in the Guest.
On Device manager (Guest) no error found.
On usb icon (Guest) I found the Host Standard USB3 eXtensible Microsoft 1.0, not the Pendrive.
No error on the prompt (Host).
But I don't find the Pendrive.

What can I do ?
I have read a lot of post.
For example, in [that post](https://superuser.com/questions/1536335/passing-through-usb3-device-in-qemu-4-2-0-from-cli) the links are not available. If the problem are relevant to the permission, what can I do ? I have run QEMU with Admin, but nothing change.
Eventually it's possible to share a folder ?

Thanks